# Как получить все комбинации списка списков Python

Tags: python

Дан список списков

```
a = [[0, 23, 3],
     [0, 24, 1],
     [1, 22, 3, 6]]
```

Как можно получить все комбинации значений подсписков:

```
0, 0, 1
0, 0, 22
0, 0, 3
0, 0, 6
0, 24, 1
.......
3, 1, 6
```

В реальном примере и подсписков самих больше и количество элементов в каждом из них тоже больше. Поэтому нужно какое-то универсальное решение.

Comment: itertools.product

Comment: спасибо большое!